# mean value theorem on an open interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know that the conditions for the mean value theorem state $f$ must be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

What happens if we change the condition to $f$ is continuous on $ (a,b)$ but not at the endpoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a constant function on $(a,b)$ where $b>a$ and specify arbitrary distinct values for $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Then $f$ is continuous and differentiable in $(a,b)$.

Now, for all $c \in (a,b)$, we have $f^\prime (c)=0$ and also

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \neq 0,$$

giving a counterexample when the required condition of mean value theorem is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be defined as

$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $x=0$}\\
x,&\text{if $0<x\leq1$}
\end{cases}
$$

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Given $a < b$, for any $\epsilon_{a} > 0$ and any $\epsilon_{b} > 0$ such that
$\epsilon_{a} + \epsilon_{b} < b - a\quad\exists\ \xi \ni$ 
$$
{{\rm f}\left(b - \epsilon_{b}\right) - {\rm f}\left(a + \epsilon_{\rm a}\right)
 \over
 b - a - \epsilon_{a} - \epsilon_{b}}
=
{\rm f}'\left(\xi\right)\,,
\qquad\mbox{where}\quad
a + \epsilon_{a} < \xi < b - \epsilon_{b}
$$