# Regarding the monotonicity through derivative

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

A corollary to Mean value theorem states that, for example,

> Assume $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and differentiable in $(a,b)$. If  $f'(x)> 0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$, then $f$ is strictly increasing in $[a,b]$.

The question is, what if $f$ were continuous in $(a,b)$, i.e. $f$ is not defined in $\{a,b\}$? For example, I want to show that $x\mapsto \tan(x)$ is strictly increasing in the open interval $(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2)$ using derivative, and the derivative is positive in that interval; but the corollary only applies to closed intervals?

Basically, $x\mapsto \tan(x)$ is continuous in any closed subsets of $(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2)$, say $[-\frac \pi 2+\epsilon,\frac \pi 2-\epsilon]$ for all small $\epsilon>0$. Should I take the infinite unions here? What is the simplest way to conclude?

Comment: $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$ iff it is strictly increasing on every $[c,d]\subset(a,b).$ Alternatively, you can rewrite the statement and the proof of the theorem: if $f$ is differentiable on an interval $I$ and $f'>0$ on $I$ then $f$ is strictly increasing on $I.$ (As a corollary, if $f$ is moreover defined and continuous on $\overline I$ then it is strictly increasing on $\overline I$.)

Comment: @AnneBauval The proof of the corollary uses Mean Value Theorem (or Rolle's lemma). See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504211/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665801, where endpoints in the closed interval is removed. This is the reason why I asked this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to cope with your situation. Let us first recall your corollary (of the mean value theorem), and state another one.

> **Corollary 1.** Assume $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. If  $f'> 0$ on $(a,b),$ then $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$.

> **Corollary 2.** Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. If $f'> 0,$ then $f$ is strictly increasing.

As you already know, MVT "implies" (in the sense: can be used to prove) Corollary 1. I claim that MVT also implies Corollary 2, either directly or via Corollary 1, and that conversely, Corollary 2 implies Corollary 1:

- MVT $\implies$ Corollary 2: Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. If $f'> 0,$ then for every $x,y\in(a,b)$ such that $x<y,$ $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=f'(c)$ for some $c\in(x,y)$ (by the MVT) hence $f(y)-f(x)>0.$
- Corollary 1 $\implies$ Corollary 2: Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. If $f'> 0,$ then (by Corollary 1) $f$ is strictly increasing on every $[c,d]\subset(a,b).$ Therefore, $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b).$
- Corollary 2 $\implies$ Corollary 1: Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. If  $f'> 0$ on $(a,b),$ then (by Corollary 2) $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b).$ There remains to check that for every $x\in(a,b),$ $f(a)<f(x)<f(b).$ Let us just prove $f(a)<f(x)$ (the other inequality can be proved similarly). Pick any $y\in(a,x).$ For every $t\in(a,y),$ we have $f(t)<f(y)$ hence by continuity, $f(a)\le f(y).$ Since $f(y)<f(x),$ we can conclude: $f(a)<f(x).$